# Base-15 conversion discrepancy

Tags: java, biginteger

Recently, I do an exercise requiring do converting base,
I used BigInteger to convert from base-15 to base 10. But when I check it against the result from a website

http://www.unitconversion.org/unit_converter/numbers-ex.html

It show that two result is not matched, I don't know why?

This is my code:

```
BigInteger bignumber = new BigInteger("1023456789ABCDEA", 15);
System.out.println(bignumber.toString(10));
```

and the result is : **442213251884616145**
the result from above website is: **442213251884616168**

I am using JDK 1.7 netbeans 7.2

Thanks

Comment: What programming language ? (Java ?) Please tag appropriately.

Comment: This is the deobfuscated code from that website: http://pastebin.com/9AFZaPci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigInteger` is correct, as confirmed by [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1023456789ABCDEA%20base%2015).

That other web site you link to is a bit iffy: when I change the last digit of the base-15 input, the base-10 output stays the same. :)

Comment: thanks, i did not know about Wolfram, i thought that website is correct but not

Comment: I think that website converts the number to JS number type (which is 64-bit floating type) before converting it to other bases. The number the OP inputs exceeds the precision of the double type, so the precision is lost.

Comment: @nhahtdh: That sounds plausible.